# How to convert the following data structure to a hierarchical data structure

Tags: python

There is an array, each element in the array is a node in the following figure, and there is a hierarchical relationship between the nodes, similar to the "tree" data structure (except that the child node can refer back to the parent node).

```
#The current data structure is in the following format
[
      {
        'id': 1,
        'name': '开始',
        'next': '2,3,4'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'name': '2号',
        'next': ''
      },
      {
        'id': 3,
        'name': '3号',
        'next': '5,8'
      },
      {
        'id': 4,
        'name': '4号',
        'next': '6'
      },
      {
        'id': 5,
        'name': '5号',
        'next': '7'
      },
      {
        'id': 6,
        'name': '6号',
        'next': ''
      },
      {
        'id': 7,
        'name': '7号',
        'next': '1,3,5'
      },
      {
        'id': 8,
        'name': '8号',
        'next': ''
      }
]
```

In the case of ensuring that the first element in the above array is the root node, please write a code to convert any of the above types of data formats into the following hierarchical format.

```
#to convert
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"开始",
    "backpoints":[ ],
    "childs":[
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"2号",
            "backpoints":[ ],
            "childs":[ ]
        },
        {
            "id":3,
            "name":"3号",
            "backpoints":[ ],
            "childs":[
                {
                    "id":5,
                    "name":"5号",
                    "backpoints":[ ],
                    "childs":[
                        {
                            "id":7,
                            "name":"7号",
                            "backpoints":[
                                "1",
                                "3",
                                "5"
                            ],
                            "childs":[ ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id":8,
                    "name":"8号",
                    "backpoints":[ ],
                    "childs":[ ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":4,
            "name":"4号",
            "backpoints":[ ],
            "childs":[
                {
                    "id":6,
                    "name":"6号",
                    "backpoints":[ ],
                    "childs":[ ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulties with?

Comment: I don't know how to convert

Comment: "please write a code" is not a valid question, we're not a free programming service. You should try converting, show your attemped code, and come to us with problems you're facing with it

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over the given list of dicts (named `nodes` in the following example) and use a dict that maps node IDs to node objects, and iterate over the node IDs in the `next` key to pre-create entries in the mapping dict as items in the `childs` sub-list if the ID does not already exist in the mapping dict, or append the ID to the `backpoints` sub-list:

```
mapping = {}
for node in nodes:
    nexts = node.pop('next')
    entry = mapping.setdefault(node['id'], {})
    entry.update({**node, **{'backpoints': [], 'childs': []}})
    if nexts:
        for n in map(int, nexts.split(',')):
            if n in mapping:
                entry['backpoints'].append(str(n))
            else:
                entry['childs'].append(mapping.setdefault(n, {}))
```

so that `mapping[nodes[0]['id']]` would return:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "开始",
    "backpoints": [],
    "childs": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "2号",
            "backpoints": [],
            "childs": []
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "3号",
            "backpoints": [],
            "childs": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "5号",
                    "backpoints": [],
                    "childs": [
                        {
                            "id": 7,
                            "name": "7号",
                            "backpoints": [
                                "1",
                                "3",
                                "5"
                            ],
                            "childs": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "name": "8号",
                    "backpoints": [],
                    "childs": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "4号",
            "backpoints": [],
            "childs": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "6号",
                    "backpoints": [],
                    "childs": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/StrikingFunctionalCrash